# EF: Method not found: 'System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.EdmModel System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbModel.get_StoreModel()'

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a solution with a shared custom "code-first" DbContext object.

Since today in one of the projects after trying to access the entities in this way

```
 using(var cx = new MyContext())
 {
    var data = cx.Persons;
 }
```

I'm getting following Exception.

```
    {"Method not found: 'System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.EdmModel System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbModel.get_StoreModel()'."}
        [System.MissingMethodException]: {"Method not found: 'System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.EdmModel System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbModel.get_StoreModel()'."}
        Data: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
        HelpLink: null
        HResult: -2146233069
        InnerException: null
        Message: "Method not found: 'System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.EdmModel System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbModel.get_StoreModel()'."
        Source: "CodeFirstStoreFunctions"
        StackTrace: "   at CodeFirstStoreFunctions.FunctionsConvention.Apply(EntityContainer item, DbModel model)\r\n   
atSystem.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.ConventionsConfiguration.ModelConventionDispatcher.Dispatch[T](T item)\r\n   
at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.ConventionsConfiguration.ModelConventionDispatcher.VisitEdmEntityContainer(EntityContainer item)\r\n   
at System.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmModelVisitor.VisitCollection[T](IEnumerable`1 collection, Action`1 visitMethod)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmModelVisitor.VisitEntityContainers(IEnumerable`1 entityContainers)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmModelVisitor.VisitEdmModel(EdmModel item)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.ConventionsConfiguration.ModelConventionDispatcher.VisitEdmModel(EdmModel item)\r\n   
at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.ConventionsConfiguration.ModelConventionDispatcher.Dispatch()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Conven
    tionsConfiguration.ApplyStoreModel(DbModel model)\r\n   
at System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbProviderManifest providerManifest, DbProviderInfo providerInfo)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbConnection providerConnection)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModel(LazyInternalContext internalContext)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryLazy`2.GetValue(TInput input)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.GetEnumerator()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TResult>.GetEnumerator()\r\n   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)\r\n   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)\r\n   at ... }
```

It's very strange because in the other projects the custom Context works fine.

What I'tried:

- Clean and Rrebuild
- Compared the connection strings

What does the message mean?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

In my case, this error was caused by mixed up entity framework packages. 'Project A' used version 6.1.3 of Entity framework. 'Project B' that was a test project for 'Project A' used version 6.0.0.

This caused exactly the error message shown above, when my tests executed.

After upgrading to 6.1.3 in both projects, the error is gone.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue I get resolved it by

1. Delete EntityFramework.dll from GAC MSIL
2. Refresh Data Model(before deletion of entityframework.dll it was not
   allowing me to add/delete table from edmx)
3. Add entityFramework.dll in GAC file using command gacutil -i entityframework.dll
4. Clean Solution
5. Build Solution

PS: Make sure the entityframework.dll version is same in all (project - GAC Files), and app config contains the connection string